# How can I solve a classification problem with a dependent variable with more than two values

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification

I have a simple NLP problem, where I have some written reviews that have a simple binary positive or negative judgement. In this case I am able to train and test as independent variables the columns of X that contain the "bags of words", namely the single  words in a sparse matrix.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 300)
#indipendent
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
#dependent
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
```

..and the  dependent variable y, that is represented by the column 1 that assume values as 0 and 1( so basically positive and negative review).

if instead of 0 and 1, I have reviews that can be voted from 1 to 5 stars should I proceed having an y variable column with values from 0 to 4?In other words I would lie to know how differ the model if instead of a binary good/bad review, the user has the possibility after his or her review to give a rating from 1 to 5.
How is called this kind of problem in machine learning?

Comment: Have you looked into multiclass? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

Comment: thanks, now I learned a lot with all these replies. I am going to upvote the others and vote for @Rishi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just multi-class classification problem. Here is a sample code from where you can get an idea. What you are calling 'dependent variable' is called class (class that the input example belongs to)

```
    label_idx = [unique.index(l) for l in labels] """ labels= class. works for your class is string or so. 
here labels can be more than two"""
    label_idx = np.array(label_idx) # just get your class into array
    vectors = np.array(vecs) # vecs are any vectorised form of your text data
    clf = LinearSVC() # classifier of your choice
    clf.fit(vectors, label_idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following link for a RandomForest multiClassifier which is one of many possible ML algorithms you can use:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier

However, my personal experience shows deep learning neural networks work better with "text data" and tree-based models are better for tabular data with numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called as multi-class classification problem as mentioned by @rishi. There is a large variety of algorithms that can solve the multi-class problem. [Look here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-algorithms)

You could make your target variable as one, which as the ratings.

```
#dependent
y = dataset.iloc[:, 'ratings'].values
```

Then, you can fit this data into the [classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier)!

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)
```